# What are some of the advantages and disadvantages of Pickle and cPickle compared to python's JSON module?

Tags: python, json, pickle

In the past I've found that pickle (and cPickle) is slower than json and has substantial problems as files approach the Gigabyte size range, while json can scale past that point.

Json also has some strong portability advantages.

What are some advantages of pickle? Is it integrated into any other python modules, or can it represent a wider range of python datatypes?

Comment: the advantage of pickle is that it knows python.

Comment: The other question is the same as mine. Thanks for pointing out the duplicate, sorry I didn't find it first.